# How can I use field expansion to expand one or two fields, while still getting all default fields for an object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, x-facebook-platform, facebook-field-expansion

On Facebook's platform, using the Graph API, how can I request default fields + one or two field expanded fields, without having to explicitly request each default field?

As far as I can tell, as soon as you field expand a single field, it overrides all the default fields.

Being able to say, `?fields=default_fields,comments.limit(10).summary(true)` would be amazing, considering how often fields change and how most objects have little overlap in the fields available on them.

Comment: No, that is not possible; when using `fields` parameter, you have to explicitly specify all fields you want (apart from the `id`, which you should get in any case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to specify fields in addition to the default.

By specifying a field, you're indicating your preference to limit (or expand) the specific data you want. As such, the defaults are overridden and you need to specify each field you want to get back.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you have a constant, etc, that specifies which fields get returned in a bare request? Could we get a shorthand we can use within field expansion to get those fields? I get why the fields change often, but because I use field expansion to reduce calls to the API, my specific calls break non-infrequently due to changes. It'd also be nice to make object agnostic calls expecting defaults + the expanded fields the objects share in common.